# It is related to core java enums

Tags: singleton, instances

what is singleton instances of the enumeration class in java?

Comment: Context, please! Where did you hear about "singleton instances of the enumeration class"?

Comment: And some details [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're talking aobut using an enum to implement the singleton pattern?

```
public enum Singleton {
   INSTANCE;
   public void singletonMethod() { ... }
}
```

Since enums were added to Java, this is the best (shortest, most correct) way to implement singletons.