# singleton with static initializer block

Tags: java, singleton

Please refer below code and help me to understand why this not a valid singleton implementation.

```
class A{
    private static A ob;

    private A(){}
    static {
        ob = new A();
    }
    public static A getInstance() {
        return ob;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to hide the empty costructor with `private A() {}`

Comment: You can drop the static initializer block and just declare it as `private static final A ob = new A();`, it is semantically identical.

Comment: @AndyTurner But declaring a `static` brackets will make the code execute even if he never requires an instance of A, won't it?

Comment: @user2651804 it is semantically identical. Try compiling it with the static initializer and with a field initializer, the resulting bytecode is the same. The field initializer *becomes* a static initializer, it's just less verbose.

Comment: Thanks friends for your responses, I forget to add private constructor. Please let me know if updated code still required any changes for a valid singleton example

Comment: @AndyTurner: I think it would not be semantically identical. Putting the code in a static block will make it thread-safe as it will be guaranteed to be executed only once. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @displayName have you tried compiling the two versions and comparing the bytecode, as suggested in my previous comment?

Answer (score 4):

It is not a valid singleton (multiple instances may be instantiated) because you get the [*default constructor*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor). Add a `private` constructor (which will prevent the default constructor from being inserted). And you probably want to override `clone()`.

```
private A() {
}

@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException(this.getClass().getName() 
            + ": is a singleton.");
}
```

I would usually use an [`enum` to implement a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-as-enum-in-java/26285591#26285591).

Comment: Thanks Elliott, but   why there is a need for clone method? i never implements cloneable

Comment: What happens if someone `clone`s a `Singleton`?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing stops me creating a new instance of `A` by calling `new A()`, so I can have multiple instances of it.

Comment: I Agree Andy, added private constructor, Please review and let me know.