# Is my service thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have a **singleton** class `MyService`, it has two functions to read & write data from/to file:

```
public class MyService {
 private static MyService instance;
 private MyFileAccessor fileAccessor;

 private MyService() {
   fileAccessor = new MyFileAccessor();
 }

 public static MyService getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
     instance = new MyService();
  }
  return instance;
 }
 // write data to file through fileAccessor object
 public void writeDataToFile(Object data){
   fileAccessor.writeToFile(data);
 }
 // read data from file through fileAccessor object
 public Object readFile() {
   return fileAccessor.readFromFile();
 }

}
```

`MyFileAccessor` class has **synchronized** functions to read & write file:

```
public class MyFileAccessor {
  private File mFile;

  public MyFileAccessor() {
    mFile = new File(PATH);
  }
  public synchronized Object readFromFile() {
    // code to read mFile
    …
  } 

  public synchronized void writeToFile(Object data) {
    // code to write data to mFile
    …
  } 
}
```

My question : Is the singleton `MyService` class **thread-safe** when my project reading & writing data from/to file through it? Are there potential concurrency issues?

**===== UPDATE ===**

Two more questions based on the answers:

**Q1.** I see the answers below about using Initialized-On-Demand idom. But isn't it enough if I just use the `synchronized` keyword on `getInstance()` **static** method?

```
public static synchronized MyService getInstance() {
 ...
}
```

Doesn't it also make the singleton instance creation atomic?

**Q2.** If I only use `MyFileAccessor` through `MyService` instance, is it still necessary to make `MyFileAccessor` a singleton or synchronized on MyFileAccessor.class ? I mean MyService is a singleton, isn't it already guaranteed only one instance is able to invoke methods in `MyFileAccessor`?

Comment: It's not a singleton, because your checking of `instance == null` and maybe assigning `instance = new MyService()` is not done atomically. Check out the [Initialization-on-demand idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom).

Comment: There may be chance of your singleton fails. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html

Comment: @AndyTurner, Do you mean when multiple threads call `MyService.getInstance()`, then it is not thread-safe? If so, how to make it safe?

Comment: @Leem.fin Yes. "Check out the Initialization-on-demand idiom.".

Comment: You should make `mFile` final in order to guarantee its visibility to all threads.

Comment: You need to make `mFile` final, otherwise other threads can see it in an uninitialized state. And you need to make the method `getInstance` synchronized to ensure that you only ever create one instance, otherwise other threads may not see your assignment to `instance` and create yet another instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have a singleton class at the moment. Because you check if `instance == null` and then maybe assign `instance = new MyService()` non-atomically, there is a chance that two threads will create instances of `MyService`.

One way to create a thread-safe singleton is to use a single-element enum:

```
enum MyService {
  INSTANCE;

  // Rest of class body.
}
```

You can now get your instance via `MyService.INSTANCE`.

An alternative is the [Initialization-on-demand idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), which makes use of the fact that a class is not initialized until it is first required:

```
class MyService {
  private static class Holder {
    private static final MyService INSTANCE = new MyService();
  }

  static MyService getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

As @Kayaman notes below, the singleton enum pattern is the currently-preferred way of doing it. I can think of reasons why you might want to use the IOD idiom, for instance if you need to extend another class (enums can't extend classes, since they already extend `Enum`; however, they can implement interfaces).

For completeness, yet another pattern is [Double-checked Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), which uses a synchronized block if `instance` is found to be `null`:

```
static MyService getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
    synchronized (MyService.class) {
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyService();
      }
    }
  }
  return instance;
}
```

---

Having done that, you should also make all fields `final`: there is a happens-before guarantee on the assignment of final fields with respect to the constructor finishing execution.

```
private final MyFileAccessor fileAccessor; // In MyService.

private final File mFile;  // In MyFileAccessor.
```

Otherwise, there is no guarantee that these fields' values will be visible to all threads.

---

You should also make `MyFileAccessor` either a singleton (e.g. using the lazy holder idiom), or make the methods synchronized on `MyFileAccessor.class`, to ensure that only one instance is able to invoke those methods at the same time.

Comment: Then there's the elephant in the room - is `FileAccessor` thread safe? Yes it is `synchronized` but it is not a singleton and it look like it always opens the same file so create more than one and you are reading and writing to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Double checked locking does work. It didn't work years ago, before the memory model was "fixed" in Java 1.5. Instead of the `Holder` idiom, I'd use the current standard best practice of [Enum singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-as-enum-in-java), which is simple, lazy and guaranteed to work.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon entirely valid large game hunting, updated.

Comment: @Andy Turner, Thanks, but I have one more question based on your answer. I am interested to know if I only use `MyFileAccessor` through `MyService,` is it still necessary to make `MyFileAccessor` a singleton or synchronized on MyFileAccessor.class ? I mean `MyService` is a singleton, isn't it already guranteed only one instance is able to invoke methods in `MyFileAccessor`?

Comment: Please see my updated questions based on your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Q1. Sure, you can make `getInstance` synchronized, it just makes it slower because you have to acquire and release the lock each time you call the method, whether or not there is any contention.

Comment: Q2. You don't have to, but you need to have some other means to **guarantee** that no other instance can be created. It's a public class; if others are using your code, they may nefariously/unwittingly create an instance and destroy the thread safety of your code. Put in the (trivial) effort now to make your code as safe as you can; don't wait for it to become a production issue that you can't track down.

Comment: @Leem.fin see my answers to your added questions in these comments.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks, I saw your answers to my updated questions. Could you please explain more about happens-before guarantee when using `final` keyword on `fileAccessor` & `mFile` ? I don't quite understand what does it mean, why it is not safe to not use `final` on them?

Comment: @Leem.fin I strongly recommend that you grab a copy of Java Concurrency In Practice, which explains about all of the things I have mentioned in my answer and comments.