# Creating a Singleton Object in Java

Tags: java, singleton

In my Java program, I am attempting to ensure that only one object of the class "ATM" is created. For this, I have a classic singleton class as below:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null) {
            uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }

}
```

How do I ensure that only one object of the class ATM is made? E.g. Where do I now put the code:

```
ATM theATM = new ATM();
```

Does this code belong in the singleton class, or within the ATM class?

Comment: @engineer - So this code needs to be within the ATM class, rather than in it's own separate Singleton class?

Comment: Singleton is a _pattern_. This is a template for writing a (non-threadsafe and error prone) singleton. I would not use this at all, and use the [`enum` singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26285591/2071828) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that `Singleton` class, because your singleton has to be `ATM`.

So, just use this in ATM.java:

```
public class ATM {

    private static ATM uniqueInstance;

    private ATM() {}

    public static ATM getInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null) {
            uniqueInstance = new ATM();
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }

}
```

Now, you can call your line:

```
ATM theATM = new ATM();
```

only if you are in the `ATM` class itself, because your constructor is `private`, but this is useless because you care about `uniqueInstance` in this situation.

If you are in a different class, you should use:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ATM theATM = ATM.getInstance();
    }

}
```

The idea of the singleton pattern is that even if you run again `ATM.getInstance();`, the same (initial) instance (`uniqueInstance`) will be returned. If it wasn't initialized before, it is initialized. Otherwise, the old instance is returned. So, this is how you are sure that you won't have multiple instances.

---

Of course, there are better implementations of the singleton pattern that are thread safe.

E.g.:

- **thread safe - lazy**:

  ```
  public class ATM {
      private static ATM uniqueInstance = null;
      private ATM(){}
      public static synchronized ATM getInstance() {
          if ( uniqueInstance == null ) {
              uniqueInstance = new ATM();
          }
          return uniqueInstance;
      }
  }
  ```
- **thread safe - eager**

  ```
  public class ATM {
      private static ATM uniqueInstance = new ATM();
      private ATM(){}
      public static ATM getInstance() {
          return uniqueInstance;
      }
  }
  ```
- **thread safe - using enum**

  ```
  public enum ATM {
      UNIQUE_INSTANCE;
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I was getting confused in that (as mentioned) a singleton is a design _pattern_ so it does not need it's own class.