# Singleton using Atomic Non Blocking Method vs Synchornized

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, atomic, nonblocking

I have tried to utilized Non Blocking Atomic Boolean API to generate singleton object instead of synchronized.

I have 2 implementations

1. Via Double Locking and Synchronized Keyword
2. Via Atomic Non Blocking Call

I believe we can have robust and better implementation via Atomic than synchronized. Please suggest if i am incorrect. Also performs some basic test for performance which favors Atomic implementation over synchronized.

Supports

```
// Lazy Initialization
// Thread-safe
// Performance improvement for corresponding calls, once the object is created

public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    static final AtomicBoolean isInitialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private Singleton() {
        // private constructor //Thread.sleep(10)

    }

    // 1st Implementation
    // Via Double Locking and Synchronized
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            // synchronized block to remove overhead
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    // if instance is null, initialize
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // 2nd Implementation + Not ThreadSafe with Null Objects.
    // Via Atomic Non Blocking Method and avoiding Synchronized
    public static Singleton getInstanceViaAtomic() {
        if (instance != null)
            return instance;

        if (isInitialized.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            return instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

**Update** @Kayaman correctly identified the above impl was not threadsafe. I fixed in the below one.

```
// 2nd Implementation + Thread Safe
// Via Atomic Non Blocking Method and avoiding Synchronized
public static Singleton getInstanceViaAtomic() throws InterruptedException {
    while(instance == null) {
        if (isInitialized.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
    }
    return instance;

}
```

Comment: It's best to use an [enum singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java). Short, lazily loaded, no synchronization necessary, hard to get wrong.

Comment: @Kayaman i second your opinion. My question is just i am curious between non blocking vs synchronized blocking behavior. if you can shed ur thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd implementation isn't thread-safe. An easy way to show it is to put a `Thread.sleep(10);` (or more) in the constructor of `Singleton`.

This causes the first thread to set `isInitialized` to `true` (while `instance` is still null), then call `new Singleton();`.

Another thread will see `instance` as `null`, it won't enter the `if` block because the boolean is now `true`, then it will return `instance` which is null.

So a race condition ending with a `NullPointerException`.

If we were to force this solution into a working one, it would have to use a spinlock and could be something like this (this is morning code, so let me know if there's something weird):

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {

    // Fast-path when singleton already constructed
    if(instance != null)
        return instance;

    // Spinlock lets the first thread through, others will spin
    while(instance == null && !isInitialized.compareAndSet(false, true))
        ;

    // First thread creates the singleton, spun threads will ignore
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new Singleton();

    return instance;
}
```

also `instance` needs to be `volatile` to ensure visibility.

The first lock to enter will clear the spinlock, because even though instance is null, the `!compareAndSet` will return false (as it succeeds the first time).

After this any thread coming in will stay in the spinlock because `instance == null` and `!compareAndSet` is `true`. When the instance constructing is finished, the spinlock will always fall through because of the first condition.

This is basically DCL with a spinlock instead of synchronized, and there's no scenario in which I think the above code would be useful.

Comment: Thanks Sir for highlighting the issue. Can you suggest if this non blocking behavior is better than synchronized blocking call?

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist no of course it's not better. It's broken as I explained in my answer, it's an incomplete singleton. That's why the `enum` way is so great, it's (almost) impossible to get wrong.

Comment: I absolutely agree over `enum`. Just for my learning, can you advice what's incomplete so i can understand broader and connect the dots.

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist well, you would have to have a spinlock on the variable...and probably `instance` as well. I'd write some example code, but unfortunately my mind isn't very "multithreaded" at the moment. I'll see if I can get you an example tomorrow.

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist updated the answer with a small spinlock example.

Comment: Thanks for the time and especially knowledge sharing.