# Getting Java locks on a singleton class, understanding why

Tags: java, performance

Let's say we have this code in a servlet container environment, java/j2ee.  It is a basic web application.  We have monitoring tools that mention that this class is getting majority of locks during execution of the request thread.  Is that only because of the singleton approach here?  If there are locks, could this code run into race conditions?  Cause a high volume of execution time?  The locks are on the singleton class.

```
public class SomeSingleton {

  private static final Thing object = new Thing();

    public static SomeSingleton instance = null;    

    private final Properties logfiles = new Properties();

    public static SomeSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            createInstance();
        }
        return instance;
    }

 
    /**
     * Imagine this method called
     * SomeSingleton.getInstance().log()
     */
    public void log(final String message) {
        try {
            synchronized (logfiles) {
            }
    }
}
```

Servlet:

```
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
      SomeSingleton.getInstance().log()
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `instance` field be `private` and `final`?

Comment: Shouldn't but isn't, going off example as is.

Comment: Well if you make that `instance` field immutable it will surely help with avoiding locks

Comment: Actually, let me restate...if you make all the fields in `SomeSingleton` immutable, it will be thread (lock) safe.

Comment: What exactly is `createInstance` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Define your singleton as an `enum`.
- Use virtual threads if your code involves blocking (if your code is not CPU-bound).

  - Protect thread-unsafe resources with a `ReentrantLock` in long-running (blocking) code. Use `synchronized` only around brief code that does not block, such as checking guards in memory.

### Just one lock, but not really a singleton

> Getting Java locks on a singleton class, understanding why

Not "locks" plural, but singular. There is only a single lock in your code, from this line: "synchronized (logfiles) {".

> The locks are on the singleton class.

The lock is *not* on your `SomeSingleton` class, if that is what your meant by "the singleton class". The lock is on the `Properties` object held in `logfiles` object.

> `SomeSingleton`

Your class is not actually a singleton, as explained in [Answer by Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77352937/642706).

You have a race condition, where multiple threads could be accessing your `getInstance` method and read a `null` before you have finished assigning an instance to `SomeSingleton instance`. At runtime, your code could actually instantiate more than one `SomeSingleton` objects.

Plus, `SomeSingleton instance` should be `private` rather than `public` if you intend access to go through `getInstance`.

### Revamped, with private constructor

You need to revamp that code. I would change it around to make a single instance available through a `public final` object reference, and make the constructor private to assure no inadvertent instantiations take place.

Change this:

```java
public class SomeSingleton {

  private static final Thing object = new Thing();

    public static SomeSingleton instance = null;    

    private final Properties logfiles = new Properties();

    public static SomeSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            createInstance();
        }
        return instance;
    }

 
    /**
     * Imagine this method called
     * SomeSingleton.getInstance().log()
     */
    public void log(final String message) {
        try {
            synchronized (logfiles) {
            }
    }
}
```

… to the following.

We mark `instance` as `public` because this is our designated access route for calling methods.

We mark `instance` as `final` to prevent re-assignment to another object.

We re-org our `static` vars together for clarity.

We add a constructor, making it `private` to avoid uncontrolled instantiation.

We initialize `logfiles` in the constructor, rather than on the declaration line, as a matter of style. Some folks like me want to see all the initialization for this object in one place, not scattered amongst declaration lines. Reasonable people may disagree.

This code instantiates `instance` in the static declaration, `… instance = new SomeSingleton();`. We no longer need your `getInstance` method. This instantiation occurs when the class loads. The `instance` field is marked `final` to prevent any other instance from being assigned.

```java
public class SomeSingleton 
{
    // Statics.
    public static final SomeSingleton instance = new SomeSingleton();
    private static final Thing thing = new Thing();  

    // Member fields.
    private final Properties logfiles;  // To enable logging.
    
    // Private constructor.
    private SomeSingleton() 
    {
        this.logfiles = new Properties() ;
    }

    /**
     * Perform logging by calling:
     * SomeSingleton.instance.log( … )
     */
    public void log( final String message ) 
    {
        synchronized ( this.logfiles ) 
        {
            …  
        }
    }
}
```

### `ReentrantLock` rather than `synchronized` for virtual threads

For compatibility with [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) in [Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21)+, we replace `synchronized` with a [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) object.

Do this only if (a) the work being performed is not entirely [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) (involves blocking), and (b) takes a while to execute. If short-lived, just use `synchronized`. Pinning the virtual thread is not a problem for a mere moment.

```java
public class SomeSingleton 
{
    // Statics.
    public static final SomeSingleton instance = new SomeSingleton();
    private static final Thing thing = new Thing();  

    // Member fields.
    private final Properties logfiles;  // To enable logging.
    private final Lock loggingLock;  // To protect logging.
    
    // Private constructor.
    private SomeSingleton() 
    {
        this.logfiles = new Properties() ;
        this.loggingLock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    /**
     * Perform logging by calling:
     * SomeSingleton.instance.log( … )
     */
    public void log( final String message ) 
    {
        this.loggingLock.lock();  // Blocks until lock becomes available.
        try 
        {
            …  // Involves blocking, such as I/O.
        } 
        finally 
        {
            this.loggingLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

### Singleton as `enum`

But even this is not ideal. Singleton pattern is surprisingly tricky business!

Current wisdom is that a singleton in Java is generally best implemented as an `enum`. For more info, see:

- The book [*Effective Java*](https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/effective-java/P200000000138) by [Dr. Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch).
- This Question, [*Implementing Singleton with an Enum (in Java)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26285520/642706)

An enum is implicitly `static` and `final`, no need to add those modifiers.

In transforming to an enum, we can delete the line: `public static final SomeSingleton instance = new SomeSingleton();`. The named enum object populates (the instantiation of our singleton) when the class loads, just the same as our `static` field did as mentioned above.

```java
public enum SomeSingleton 
{
    // enum
    INSTANCE ;

    // Statics.
    private static final Thing thing = new Thing();  

    // Member fields.
    private final Properties logfiles;  // To enable logging.
    private final Lock loggingLock;  // To protect logging.
    
    // Private constructor.
    private SomeSingleton() 
    {
        this.logfiles = new Properties() ;
        this.loggingLock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    /**
     * Perform logging by calling:
     * SomeSingleton.INSTANCE.log( … )
     */
    public void log( final String message ) 
    {
        this.loggingLock.lock();  // Blocks until lock becomes available.
        try 
        {
            …  // Involves blocking, such as I/O.
        } 
        finally 
        {
            this.loggingLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So one lock in the original code but could be a bottleneck.

Comment: @BerlinBrown I don’t see a “bottleneck”. Using threads helps overall performance. The cost of multi-threading is protecting access to resources. Protecting access means using locks/synchronized. Of course we should minimize the amount of code covered by locks/synchronized. But locking is a necessary part of handling concurrency. If you use the term “bottleneck” to mean a problem area in the code that unnecessarily restricts performance, I would disagree. Such **locking is the necessary price for gaining overall performance** through threading. (Virtual threads can further boost those gains.)

Comment: A very worthwhile answer

Answer (score 4):

Not a singleton!
Two threads can both see a null instance. And then two instanced are created. Though one is stored in the global variable.

Logging generally is single threaded (I/O!). However you could have a faster queue and only synchronized put the already made log message into the queue.

Answer (score 1):

When you have huge number of requests, calling this log() method can become a bottleneck and cause the application to slowdown. This is because every request will need to get a lock while executing that synchronised block in the log() method.
Though I dont see any reason for race condition, but it will definitely slowdown the application when the requests a high.

Comment: Ok, so the instance is a singleton and the lock is on the main object of question.

Comment: Lock will be acquired on "logfiles" object as mentioned in the synchronized block of your code.

Comment: The race condition that you don’t see lives in the `getInstance()` method. Multiple threads could be accessing that method, resulting in multiple “singleton” objects rather than a single one.